# Title not centered in Android Toolbar widget with customview added

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, material-design

I am  trying to create a wearable app where I need to add a custom layout to toolbar ,which contains TextView in relative layout with attribute android:layout_center_in_parent set to true.But the problem is the TextView does not appear in center of ToolBar. Can anyone help me how to display the  TextView in center for ToolBar .

I used the used the below code to add customview for Toolbar and my layouts as below :

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = ( android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
    //    toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        LayoutInflater mInflater= LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_custom_view, null);
        toolbar.addView(mCustomView);
```

My activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
   >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_box="all">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/framelayout"
        >
    </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>


toolbar.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
 >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

toolbar_custom_view.xml
=======================

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Patient List"
    android:id="@+id/title"
   android:layot_center_in_parent="true"
    android:gravity="center"

    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you try setting layout_gravity = "center"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this .. jsut change TextView xml code. if you change `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width="match_parent"` then it will be horizontally center..

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Patient List"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

if you change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `match_parent` then your   textview also will be vertically center ...